# laravel debugbar package - problem with views

Tags: php, laravel, phpdebugbar

PHP Version: 7.4.29
Laravel Version = 5.7.29

I have installed laravel debugbar and it is displaying fine. Whenever I click on any part of the APP i am using (thus the version as this is an older app and it hasn't been updated) such as: link/tab/button.. in the debugbar for a split seconds it shows which view template is used and then it disappears and displays a message; '0 templates were rendered'. It happens every time. I couldn't find any information about this issue. Is there anything I can do to get the '0 templates were rendered' error fixed?

Comment: Try to remove view cache. By this command "php artisan optimize:clear"

Comment: there should be a dropdown of request history check if there's any request that is coming right after the one that rendered a view. Debugbar has history for all requests but will only show the one selected

Comment: I've tries optimizing cashe as advised but no luck. 
@apokryfos  you were right. There is a history and there are two more requests after that. The number of requests differes but makes the list of views disappear. However I can choose from the dropdown list which one I want and I get to see the view OK.